# Connect DB2 to Excel

Tags: excel, db2

I am trying to connect DB2 to Excel using ado connection string.Could you please let me know whats wrong with the code

Also it's a local setup on my desktop and can anyone tell me how to find hostname and userid.

```
Sub Import_data_from_db2()


Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection

Dim sConnString As String

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

' create the connection
sConnString = "Provider=IBMDADB2;Database=Sample;" & _
              "Hostname=localhost;Protocol=TCPIP;" & _
              "Port=50000;Uid=db2admin;Pwd=xx;"

'Open connection
cnn.Open sConnString

strQry = "SELECT * FROM ORDERS"
With rs
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .Open strQry, cnn
End With

Sheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Are you running the database on the localhost? If not, then that's the obvious problem.

hostname is the name of the machine that is running the database. You can also use the IP address if you have it.

UserID will depend on what you have configured in the database.

Comment: I am running it on local desktop and db2 is installed on same desktop. While installation I selected  "None -use local user account" and by default username was db2admin

Comment: Is TCPIP enabled for the database?

Comment: Its giving me error

Comment: Error [DB2/NT64] SQL0204N "DB2ADMIN.ORG" is an undefined name. SQLSTATE=42704